# Delphi - for - loop

Tags: function, delphi, for-loop

is there solution in Delphi 7 for deynamically creating for-loop cycles?

for example, i want to have a function that generates 1..n for-cycles

for example:

```
function generate_binary(var number_of_loops:integer):string
var x:word
begin
 for x:=1 to number_of_loops do begin
  for ...  cycle 1
    ...
    ...
    ...
  for ... cycle[x]
    //code
  end; //cycle n

  end; //cycle[x]
 end;
end;
```

is there some code for doing that?  Or i must manually set every for..  cycles?

Comment: I cannot understand the question at all. Can you perhaps let us know what the underlying problem is

Comment: The idea of the loop is that you don't have to repeat the code. The outer loop, `for x:=1 to number_of_loops do`, makes sure that the inner loop, `for ...  cycle`, is executed number_of_loops  times.

Comment: In this function, i dont want to have fixed number of "for" cycles, but dynamically generated number of for..loops  based on number_of_loops parameter, i dont know if this is possible

Comment: For nested cycles recursion is rather simple solution. But it is not clear here. Show your real problem, otherwise it looks like so-called "XYZ-problem"

Comment: How is the number of cycles generated from `number_of_loops` ? Perhaps explain what you mean by `cycle`

Comment: why exactly do you think you need a variable number of `for` loops instead of a variable number of **iterations**?

Comment: or perhaps describe a real world example

Comment: real problem:  I have string of varible 10-30 bytes length that represents a binary.  I know there will be (for example)  7x"1" and rest will be "0"  I know the exact number of "1"'s but dont know their position in the string.. I can generate this string, but finding elegant solution.

Comment: So you are converting an array of integers (bytes) which all happen to be 1 or 0 to a string?

Comment: yes i want to collect all combinations of strings to array that have exact number of "1"'s and rest is 0.  But number of 1 is variable , and length of string is variable too

Comment: ok - give us an example of the data you might want to push into this function, and the expected result (in your question) and i am sure someone can help

Comment: when i am calling this function, i know the length of output string, also know the number of "1"''s in this string, i just dont know their positions - i want to catch all combinations and store them to string array..  Maybe this function is not the best solution, maybe there is something else for my problem

Comment: I am a little concerned you are mixing up `string` and `array`

Comment: If you would present your underlying problem, rather than your solution, then we'd be able to give you much better help. Please stop fighting us. Please edit the question to ask how to solve your underlying problem. Present it clearly with example input and output.

Comment: my english is the problem, i dont want to fight :)  so i need string generator that will generate strings (binaries) of fixed length with fixed number of '1' and rest will be '0'  and all combinations.. That's all i want to do

Comment: Your problem is called "generation of combinations". There are some examples in Delphi section of SO. The shortest code - recursive.

Comment: That sounds a little clearer

Comment: I have recursion now.. I know the length of string so i am using now function  [code]  power(2,length_of_string)[/code] and generating all combinations and validating number of '1's and storing to another string array only acceptable results.. But the problem is, it takes more than 1 hour with 32 digits (2^32)

Comment: Please don't ask the question in comments. Please ask it clearly in an edit to the question. Please remove all talk of for loops and state the underlying problem clearly. Then let us help show you the best ways to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Instead of working with strings, work with an integer. A 32-bit integer is big enough to store all your 1s and 0s, and will be MUCH faster.

Comment: or post the actual code you have written - the one that takes so long

Comment: my actual code is maybe 1400 lines long.  In this post i just wanted to know, if thre is a solution for generating dynamically for cycles... thats all..

Comment: There's no possible syntax for a variable number of nested for loops. Recursion is the way it's normally done.

Comment: Oh, in that case the answer is simple. There's no way to dynamically generate for loops. Are you happy with that answer?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou and David,   - thanks for answers, yes this is answer too, and  i am accepting that as answer, thank you

Comment: One (very slow) way to do it without recursion is to loop through all possible values of an integer, and count the number of bits which are 1. If there are the required number of 1s, output that value.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou  - yes i have that code implemented.. but it takes too long for me (1 hour / big cycle)  and i need to repeat it more times.. Thats why i asked..

Comment: @Fero You've accepted an answer that does not answer the question you asked. You said, *"I just wanted to know, if there is a solution for generating dynamically for cycles."* But the answer you accepted does not address that at all. Now, the answer you accepted addresses the underlying problem which you, in spite of repeated prompting, would not actually present in the question. If you want to get the best out of this site please visit the [help] and read carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not direct answer to the topic question, but an example of particular problem solving. There are more effective methods of generation (especially for numbers, not for strings).

Look at this recursive code to generate all strings with predefined length and number of 1's. Note that output size will very large for big Len *(number of combination C(N,K) is exponential function)*

```
  procedure Generate01Combination(Len, OnesLeft: Integer; s: string);
  begin
    if Len = 0 then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s)
    else begin
      if Len > OnesLeft then
        Generate01Combination(Len - 1, OnesLeft, s + '0');
      if OnesLeft > 0 then
        Generate01Combination(Len - 1, OnesLeft - 1, s + '1');
    end;
  end;

begin
  Generate01Combination(5, 2, '');
end;
```

outputs

```
00011
00101
00110
01001
01010
01100
10001
10010
10100
11000
```

Comment: @Fero - It would be nice if you were to post back the performance of this function compared to your own

Comment: @MBo  this is effective enough for me, it will definitely speed up my application by 2000%  Hugh - I will post later if that helped , thanks for help

Comment: @Mbo I notice that the first half of the sequence is (almost) a mirror image of the second half.  Can that be leveraged?

Comment: @Hugh Jones Yes, every non-palindromic combination has mirrored 'sister'. But I suppose that generation might be faster than reversing.

Comment: @MBo Well put.  I was thinking of setting each string in pairs, though.  I am trying to figure how the next order of symmetry might be leveraged ... cannot see it

Comment: OK I tested code from @MBo  and working good, instead of adding result to memo lines i am adding results to string array (more than 1 million results)  - was generated in 25 seconds..  My old code generated the same result in 1 hours and 7 minutes..  Thanks for help

Comment: @Hugh Jones Are you interested in effective generation of some combinatorial objects? As strings? Numbers as binary sequences?

Comment: @Mbo - the problem has my interest because it is entertaining.

Comment: @HughJones i think more interesting job would be parallelize it. Using something like OmniThreadLibrary. At home i have 3-cores CPU, so there should be a way to make it at least 2 times faster...
 
With this specific example - using `Pipeline` pattern and `(Len, OnesLeft: Integer; s: string);` can be made into a packet that would be fed into the source pipe (`iOmniBlockingCollection`) again. Then parallelization is given for free. Except that `if Len = 0 then` should not touch VCL but instead put to output pipe. And `TTimer` on the main form would every 0.25 sec flush it to Memo

Comment: Here are results at Phenom X3 710 2.1GHz CPU : http://imgur.com/F8E1GmF 
Only single core was used though, would have to think how to make it parallelized. Sources and Win32 EXE: http://rghost.ru/6GWWHq9P2

Comment: @Fero You said `i am adding results to string array`. How do you calculate final length of the array and set it before the generation of strings started? PS. Don't tell me you change the array length per every new string! That would be an awful idea that slows you down badly!

Comment: @HughJones also pipeline approach would be a good thing for servers - first packet of, for example, 1000 patterns might be sent to consumer while the generation of the rest is still ongoing. Reaction time and full completion time are decoupled for free.

Comment: I implemented OTL-based multithreading approach. As was expected that required memory copying and multiple FastMM calls, which is uni-threaded by design, so results were even worse than I expected - http://imgur.com/NCxBY7l  // I could enhance it here and there but that would clearly overflow the topic-started experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can kind of "generate loops" - if you enclose them into procedures and pass those procedures as procedure pointers.

But you said `for ...  cycle[1]` - WHAT is that "..." ? Is it `for I := 1 to 4 do cycle[1]()` ? Or is it `for I := cycle[1] to 10 do ;` ? It all fits in!

So, well, - and yes, you indeed came with [XYZ problem](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal),- I will make an answer that formally fits, I think, but is hardly to help you with your own problem.

```
type TLoopProc = procedure(const LoopCount: integer);

procedure Loop1(const LoopCount: integer); var i: integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to LoopCount do ShowMessage('Loop1 loop is burning!');
end;

procedure Loop2(const LoopCount: integer); var i: integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to LoopCount do ShowMessage('Loop2 loop is burning!');
end;

procedure Loop3(const LoopCount: integer); var i: integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to LoopCount do ShowMessage('Loop3 loop is burning!');
end;

procedure Loop4(const LoopCount: integer); var i: integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to LoopCount do ShowMessage('Loop4 loop is burning!');
end;

var Loops: array[1..4] of TLoopProc; 

function generate_binary(const number_of_loops:integer):string
var x,y:word;
begin
 Result := '1234';
 for x := 1 to number_of_loops do begin
   for y := 1 to x do begin
       Loops[y](x+y);
   end;
 end;
end;

BEGIN
  Loops[1] := Loop1;
  Loops[2] := Loop1;
  Loops[3] := Loop1;
  Loops[4] := Loop1;

  generate_binary(4);
END.
```

See, formally that does call that ever increasing number of loops.
Those loops which bodies are contained inside their own procedures.
Not that I think you really can apply that to your real task.

But coming back to your real task, it is very very different.
You are given two numbers: N <= L with N being number of "1" to position in the string of Length L.

To me it looks a slightly hidden example of [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Can you position one single "1" in the string? I think you can.
But if you have all the strings with a single "1" - can you position the second "1" to the right of it? And then the 3rd "1" ?

So we would not search for the strings, we would search for ones' positions, sequences like 4-6-8-9-15-16-29-....

```
var results: iJclStringList; 
// here it is just like TStringList, but interface-based, thus needs no `.Free`

type OnePositions = array of integer;

procedure Error;
begin
  raise Exception.Create ('We badly screwed'); // or whatever you would make it do
end;

procedure StoreResult( const L: integer; const P1: OnePositions );
var R: string; i,Prev1,Next1: integer;
begin
  R := StringOfChar( '0', L );
  Prev1 := 0;

  // if those Low/High functions are not yet implemented in Delphi7,
  // you may run the loop from 0 to Prev(Length(P1))
  // to go through all the P1 array elements
  for i := Low(P1) to High(P1) do begin 
     Next1 := P1[i]; // position for next "1"
     if Next1 > Length(R) then Error; // outside of string
     if Prev1 >= Next1 then Error;   //  Next "1" is left of previous "1"
     R[Next1] := '1';
     Prev1 := Next1;     // tracing what was the right-most "1" inserted
  end;

  Results.Add(R);
end;

// L - string length, thus maximum position of "1"
// StartAt - the leftmost (minimal) position of the 1st left "1" to place
//    positions < StartAt already were taken
// Rest1s - how many "1" left to be placed (we still have to place) 
procedure PositionRest(var Pos: OnePositions; const L, StartAt, Rest1s: integer);
var Max, idx, NextRest1s, i: integer;
begin
  idx := Length(Pos) - Rest1s; // number of "1" we are setting now
  NextRest1s := Rest1s - 1;    // how many "1"s to be set by next calls
  Max := L - NextRest1s;       // rightmost part of string we have to leave free for next "1" to be placed

  for i := StartAt to Max do begin
    Pos[idx] := i;     // placing our dear "1" here or there
    if NextRest1s = 0  // did we maybe just positioned the last "1" ?
       then StoreResult( L, Pos )
       else PositionRest( Pos, L, i+1, NextRest1s);
  end;
end;

procedure GenerateAll( const L,N: integer );
var Ones: OnePositions;
begin
  results := JclStringList(); 
  SetLength(Ones,N);
  PositionRest(Ones, L, 1, N);

  Memo1.Lines.Text := results.Text;
  results := nil; 
end;

var L: integer = 20; N: integer = 7;

GenerateAll( L,N );
```

Here are results at Phenom X3 710 2.6GHz CPU from CodeTyphon 5.60 and Delphi XE2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt4CO.jpg - 4 variants.

Example:
[image: Strings of N ones across L chars]

Only single core was used, would have to think how to make it parallelized;

Sources and Win32 EXE: http://rghost.ru/7lYwX2B4Y  and http://rghost.ru/8RHmCKF4D
*Project1 built by CT 5.60 and Project2 built by Delphi XE2*

PS. Some general advices.

- Whenever you can - use `const` parameters to functions. Only use `var` parameters when you know what it is and why you do need that. It is very rarely needed !
- Do not use `word` for looping. Today CPU runs in 32 bits or 64 bits ( for Delphi 7 - only 32 bits ) - so use CPU-native type `integer` or `cardinal`, it would make it slightly easier for the hardware and 65535 maximum value for `word` might be too small sometimes.
- Delphi 7 is good but old. Did you purchased it? Why to stick with it today? I think you better either purchase modern Delphi version or take free Lazarus/FPC suite (i'd stick with CodeTyphon distro, without controversial `Orca`);

PPS. I implemented OTL-based multithreading approach.

- On a somewhat good note, I had to implement exactly `dynamic number of loops` approach.
- As was expected MT-decoupling required extensive memory copying and multiple FastMM calls, which is uni-threaded by design, so multithreading was nothing but illusion and results were even worse than I expected - [image: Naïve FastMM-thrashing OTL dyna-for-loops implementation]
- still even that crippled MT-ing would provide to "show first 100 results while others are not being calculated yet.
- I could enhance it here and there, getting rid of intermediate dynamics arrays (using lists and pointers instead) and switching to MT-oriented Heap Memory Manager, but that would clearly overflow the topic-started experience. It would be challenging to make most fast implementation, but since no one cares, then be it. Still this task was interesting synthetic example for pushing some OTL features and bounds.